How to delete Containers in Azure Storage account with the creation date
I need to delete Containers in Azure Storage account with the creation date of more than 1 year as we create container for every month.
I have tired using Azure Storage Lifecycle management , but we are not able to delete container but we can delete inside files.
Is there a way to delete container itself from Azure / Terraform ?
I want to delete the highlighted container automatically Via terraform .
Azure portal


any code you tried so far @AshrafBaig

No ... I thought Storage lifecycle will work ... But it is meant only for files . Used below one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002306/terraform-code-not-creating-multiple-rules-in-azure-storage-lifecycle/79002821?noredirect=1#comment139303614_79002821

You can delete this using CLI commands and terraform doesnt differentiate resource based on time and date If you still wanna use terrafrom to do this you can pass these CLI commands inside null resource using terraform @AshrafBaig

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: you haven't shown any details (code/script/data/behavior/errors/etc). Please read [ask] and then edit to provide a [mcve]. Right now, you've only posted a set of requirements, and left it to the Community to solve for you.


Deleting a container inside the storage account based on time of creation/modification using terraform.

This requirement mentioned is not directly possible using terraform as it doesn't support the functionality based on time stats.
In order to achieve this requirement, we need use CLI commands for this which has the privilege to fetch the metadata info of the resource. If you still want to use terraform to achieve this, you can use null resource.
Initially I tested to delete the containers which are 2 days old as shown below

Configuration:
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Resource group name"
  type        = string
  default     = "vinay-rg"
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "Storage account name"
  type        = string
  default     = "testsamoeksas"
}

resource "null_resource" "delete_old_containers" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOT
      #!/bin/bash

      storageAccount="${var.storage_account_name}"
      cutoffDate=$(date -d '-2 days' +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")  # here is tried to set this for 2 days ago containerss

     
      delete_if_old() {
          local containerName=$1

          # Get the last modified date of the container
          lastModified=$(az storage container show \
              --name $containerName \
              --account-name $storageAccount \
              --auth-mode login \
              --query properties.lastModified \
              --output tsv)

          if [[ -z "$lastModified" ]]; then
              echo "Error: Could not retrieve the last modified date for container: $containerName"
              return
          fi

          
          lastModifiedEpoch=$(date -d "$lastModified" +%s)
          cutoffDateEpoch=$(date -d "$cutoffDate" +%s)

          # Compare lastModified date with the cutoff date (2 days ago)
          if [[ $lastModifiedEpoch -lt $cutoffDateEpoch ]]; then
              echo "Deleting container: $containerName (Last Modified: $lastModified)"
              az storage container delete \
                  --name $containerName \
                  --account-name $storageAccount \
                  --auth-mode login
          else
              echo "Skipping container: $containerName (Last Modified within the last 2 days)"
          fi
      }

      
      list=$(az storage container list \
          --query "[].name" \
          --account-name $storageAccount \
          --auth-mode login \
          --output tsv)

      for containerName in $list; do
          delete_if_old $containerName
      done
    EOT
  }
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-containers-cli#delete-containers
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_container

Can we make this script to run automatically for every 24 Hrs or something like that in terraform code ? or we need to use cron job in CLI script without terraform  ?

yes @AshrafBaig its possible to achieve this requirement
